# unable to create a SerializerMutation without errors, but data is created

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I do not why but when I try to create new data using serializermutation, data is created but graphiql return an error. Here is my code.

*graphene(2.1)*
_graphene_django(2.0.0)_

**models**

```
class CompanyRole(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Company role')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Company roles')
```

**serializers**

```
class CompanyRoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CompanyRole
        fields = ('name',)
```

**mutations**

```
class CreateCompanyRole(SerializerMutation):

    class Meta:
        serializer_class = CompanyRoleSerializer

class CompanyRoleMutation(AbstractType):
        create_company_role = CreateCompanyRole.Field()
```

**schema**

```
class Query(CompanyRoleQuery,
            CompanyQuery,
            graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


class Mutation(CompanyRoleMutation,
               graphene.ObjectType):
    pass


schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query, mutation=Mutation, types=[
    CompanyRoleType,
    CompanyType,
])
```

**this is the query used**

```
mutation {
  createCompanyRole(input:{name:"name"}){
    errors {
      field
      messages
    }
    name    
  }
}
```

**and this is the error**

```
{
  "data": {
    "createCompanyRole": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "SubclassWithMeta_Meta object argument after ** must be a mapping, not CompanyRole",
      "locations": [
        {
          "column": 3,
          "line": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I can access to the new data from the admin. Anyone could help me?